# How to extract a local user's username from an R Shiny server?

Tags: r, shiny

In a local R session I can easily capture a user's local username using `Sys.info()["username"]`.

I'm attempting to access the same information from users of an R Shiny app I'm developing so that different information will be displayed to different users. I'd like to avoid having users input their username and instead let the app automatically detect the user.

However, the problem I'm having is that when I attempt to implement this code in my Shiny application the username is consistently returned as "shiny".

Here is a small app I created to test this:

UI:

```
# ui.R

fluidPage(
  textOutput("user")
)
```

Server:

```
# server.R

function(input, output) {
  output$user <- renderText({
    Sys.info()["user"]
  })
}
```

Is it possible to extract a user's local username from an R Shiny server?

Comment: No. For security reasons there should be no way for a remote website to access your local user name. You'll have to ask their user or provide some other sort of login mechanism to your application.

Comment: That's understandable. Would there be any other sort of unique consistent identifier I could get which could be used to customize a shiny app for a specified user?

Comment: There's been an aggressive push by browsers to now allow user tracking that's done by so many internet ads. As a result you really can't easily track users that are not logged in your your system. if you need to track users, you need to set up some sort of authentication system. Or maybe just track settings in browser cookies.